# Automatically logging into a website from the desktop

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, active-directory, authentication

If we have a link on a users desktop to a website, is there any way to automatically log them into that website using their windows username and password?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using the Active Directory. Maybe this article can help you.

This: [Retrieve UserName by Searching in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125352/can-i-retrieve-the-domain-name-and-user-name-by-searching-active-directoy-using-c)

Comment: The website uses an LDAP connection. It's finding a way of automatically using the users window credentials so the user doesnt have to type them into the website / intranet

Comment: Ok. I'm doing it in my Web App, let me finish and I can share you the code.

Answer (score 0):

The windows login system and the website have totally different mechanisms. You're windows password is stored locally on your machine however the website password is stored remotely on a server. hence it does not make sense to login on a website with your local password automatically.

Comment: agreed, that's my first reaction. Just wondering if there is any sideways thinking I could use for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only for local Intranets hosted on the current domain. If this is what your're after you need to set the authentication mode in the config file.

[.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It is a local intranet, however it's running on a Linux Server

Comment: Ah... then the short answer is: no. Or: not an easy way, at least. You might consider SSO libraries that would allow the Linux server to accept Windows-integrated authentication, or perhaps use client certificates for authentication.

Comment: Thanks - you've just given me a glimmer of hope and some direction. I'll let you know if I find a solution.